# What assymbly reference do you use for AuthorizationResult in a custom AuthorizationAttribute

Tags: c#, authorization, windows-authentication

I have been going crazy over this problem. I am creating a custom authorization for users on my network. I'm using Windows Authentication. I am trying to follow an example I found on MSDN on how to do so. only problem is AuthorizationResult giving me the type or namespace could not be found error. I have tried using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations does not clear the error. What reference do I need for this? Also my controller can't find the my customAuthorization class?

Here is my method class for my CustomAuthorization here is where AuthorizationResult is throwing error

```
protected override AuthorizationResult IsAuthorized(System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal principal, AuthorizationContext authorizationContext)
    {
        if(authorizationContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("hello"))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return base.AuthorizeCore(authorizationContext.HttpContext);
    }
```

Here is the call on my controller

```
[AuthorizeRoleAttribute]//does not find my class
public class HomeController : Controller
{
```

Class definition for customAttribute

```
public class AuthorizeRoleAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
```

Comment: The [Attribute] suffix is inferred by the compiler... Try decorating your controller with [AuthorizeRole] instead.

Comment: @MattMurrell thanks for the clarification! but it didn't work.

Comment: @MattMurrell is there a reference I need for it as well

Comment: Can you show the class definition for your custom authorization code?

Comment: @MattMurrell added good sir!

Comment: I would try System.Web.Http or System.Net.Http.  Is this a MVC project  or a Web API?  What Version?

Comment: @MattMurrell 4.5 is my version and MVC

Comment: How can you `return true;` if the return type of the method is `AuthorizationResult`? Post the exact error given by C# compiler found in Visual Studio Error window.

Answer (score 1):

The **AuthorizationResult** resides in **System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.dll**
Ensure that you have referenced this assembly. The reason why it doesn't pickup your custom attribute class is that it cannot compile for it is missing the assembly...

Comment: Yep, as shown here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.authorizationresult(v=vs.91).aspx